# RabbitMQ job queus completion indicator event

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying out RabbitMQ with springboot. I have a main process and within that process I am creating many number of small tasks that can be processed from other workers. From the main process perspective, I like to know when all of these tasks are completed so that it can move to next step. I did not find a easy way to query rabbitmq if the tasks are complete.

One solution I can think of is to store these tasks in a database and when each message is completed, update the database with COMPLETE status. Once all jobs are in COMPLETE status, the main process can know the jobs are COMPLETE and it can move to next step o fits process.

Another solution I can think of is  that the main process maintain the list of jobs that is being sent to other workers. Once each worker completes it's job, it can send a message to the main process indicating the job is complete. Then the Main process can mark the job is complete and remove the item from the list.Once the list is empty, the main process will know the jobs are complete and it can move to next step of it's work.

I am looking to learn best practice on how other people have dealt this kind of situation. I appreciate for any suggestion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to query RabbitMQ for this information.

The best way to approach this is with the use of a [process manager](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html).

The basic idea is to have your individual steps send a message back to a central process that keeps track of which steps are done. When that main process receives notice that all of the steps are done, it lets the system move on to the next thing.

The details of this approach are fairly complex, but I do have a blog post that covers [the core of a process manager from a JavaScript/NodeJS perspective](http://derickbailey.com/2015/08/10/managing-workflow-in-long-running-javascript-processes/).

You should be able to find something like a "process manager" or "saga" as they are sometimes called, within your language and RabbitMQ framework of choice. If not, you should be able to write one for your process without too much trouble, as described in my blog post.

Comment: Thank you Derick. I will check out your blog post.